# Jenkins Maven plugin error "maven-release-plugin:jar:3.8.2 is missing"

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependencies

I am new hear but i have gone through numerous posts and websites and finally am posting as I am not sure what else to do. Please excuse if the formatting or the way i have posted is not correct.  1st time here as i said.
If i directly run `mvn clean package deploy` the build is successful.
But fails when i run the build from jenkins.

I am getting the following error in Jenkins when trying to run a build

```
Downloaded from central: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/first-libs-release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.5.3/maven-release-plugin-2.5.3.jar (53 kB at 3.5 MB/s)
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:3.8.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.785 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-20T21:12:36+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.8.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:3.8.2 was not found in http://localhost:8081/artifactory/first-libs-release during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
Build step 'Conditional steps (multiple)' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

my pom.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>devops</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>devops</name>
    <description>DevOps demo project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>first-libs-release</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/first-libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>first-libs-snapshot</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/first-libs-snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:rahul-9911/devops.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:rahul-9911/devops.git</developerConnection>
    <url>git@github.com:rahul-9911/devops.git</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The version for maven-release-plugin is wrong... https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/ The available versions are: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-release-plugin

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for the reply.
Do i just edit the pom file or do i download the 2.5.3 and place it in some folder?

Comment: Also i wanted to mention again, that there is no error when i run mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform

The release plugin error is seen in jenkins. So could there be some plugin/maven/java issue?

Comment: I have narrowed it down to

```
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:pom:3.8.2 from [central (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/first-libs-release, default, releases), snapshots (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/first-libs-snapshot, default, releases+snapshots)]
```

i am not sure why it is looking for the release plugin 3.8.2.  i have checked pom.xml, settings.xml, mvn-scm...all possible places. but i just cant figure out WHY it is looking for this 3.8.2 plugin

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally found the problem.
The maven-release-version was incorrect. Already knew as pointed by @khmarbaise but WHICH ONE?

After a day of struggling I realized it was the pom.xml on GIT that was being pulled.
This one had the wrong version *3.8.2*

So I corrected the POM.XML on GIT and corrected the release version.

FINALLY a success!!